# Инициализация поля наследника через указатель на базовый класс.

Tags: c++

Как провести инициализацию? Прочитал несколько статей, но конкретного ответа не нашел. Необходим совет.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:    
    A() { cout << "const A work"; }
    virtual ~A() { cout << "Des A work"; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int b;
    B() { cout << "const B work"; }
    ~B() { cout << "Des B work"; }
};

int main() {
    A *pt=new B;
    pt->b=3;
    delete pt;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Простой, но неправильный путь — сделать преобразование типов:

   ```
   static_cast<B*>(pt)->b = 3;
   ```

   (Если вы в точке преобразования типов не имеете гарантии точного типа, вам пригодится `dynamic_cast`.)
2. Если вам нужно работать конкретно с классом `B`, то и объявляйте указатель на `B`.

   ```
   B *pt = new B;
   pt->b = 3;
   ```
3. Инициализация полей должна быть внутренним делом самого класса, а не внешнего кода. Правильнее будет инициализировать поле в конструкторе:

   ```
   class B : public A {
       int b;
   public:
       B(int b_) : b(b_) { cout << "const B work"; }
       ~B() { cout << "Des B work"; }
   };

   A* pt = new B(3);
   delete pt;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Можете сделать виртуальную функцию которая будет задавать значение, к примеру как-то так:

```
virtual void Ax (int a) = 0;
```

В классе родителе, потом переопределив её в наследнике.

```
 void Ax (int a) {
     b = a;
 }
```